# How can I create separate Bamboo plans for maven modules?

Tags: git, maven, bamboo

Currently, we have a multi-module maven project in Git. Say, if I try to setup a Bamboo plan for **module1**, Bamboo only has an option to provide project URL (git@gitlab.xxx.com:projectA.git), which when I provide builds all the modules (**module1**, **module2**, **module3**, **module4**) instead of only **module1**.

```
projectA
  module1
  module2
  module3
  module4
```

Additional information, 
we have a parent pom in projectA and child pom's within the modules.
We use Bamboo version 6.1.0

Answer (score 0):

When configuring a repository in Bamboo, there is a section "Change detection options" which allows you to include or exclude certain files based on a regular expression. Using this, you can have a certain build plan trigger only on changes in a certain subfolder of your repository (while it is still possible to fetch the entire repository when building, so any changes to the parent pom are included as well).

The regular expression would probably look something like this (untested!):

```
^projectA/module1*$
```

[image: bamboo-change-detection]